# Memory leak when rotating the picture

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

I've made a short test program for continuously rotating the .jpg picture in the form starting from [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

```csharp
private void DrawImagePointF(PaintEventArgs e)
{
             
    // Create image.
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile("SampImag.jpg");
             
    // Create point for upper-left corner of image.
    PointF ulCorner = new PointF(100.0F, 100.0F);
             
    // Draw image to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner);
}
```

I am aware this might be quite unusual way of rotating the picture but the code does work as expected - the only problem is **there is a memory leak** on every timer tick and I'd like to understand the cause and how to avoid it.

This is the code causing the memory leak:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Picture_rotation {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        Image jpg;
        float angle = 0f;
        PointF ulCorner = new PointF(50f, 50f);
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            jpg = Image.FromFile("picture.jpg");
        }

        private void DrawImagePointF(PaintEventArgs e) {

            ((Bitmap)jpg).SetResolution(e.Graphics.DpiX, e.Graphics.DpiY);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Rotate(jpg, angle), ulCorner);

        }

        // interval = 100
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            angle = ++angle % 360;
            Invalidate();       // to invoke Form1_Paint()

        }

        private Bitmap Rotate(Image original, float angle) {

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(original, new Point(0, 0));
            g.Dispose();
            return bmp;     // memory leak?
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            DrawImagePointF(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you measure memory leak? because the GC will only kick in when needed. Which is not until a certain amount of memory is consumed.

Comment: Additionally, always use a `using` statement if its possible.

Comment: @TomTom: The used RAM in Visual Studio Process Memory view is increasing on every timer tick, even if the timer interval is 10000.

Comment: Yeah, but as I said... and ESPECIALLY IN THE DEBUGGER, memory is not released immediately.

Comment: @TheGeneral: With `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {...}` the result is the very same.

Comment: Are you disposing the bitmap at some point? or just creating oodles and not worrying about it?

Comment: @TomTom: How long do you think it would take for the garbage collector to free the memory and how long it would take for the debugger to show the RAM has been freed? The used RAM grows for a few MB per second starting from about 30 MB and after a minute the used RAM is already near 1000 MB.

Comment: It is not a how long. It is how much memory. And it should be faster outside the profiler. Did you try using the memory profiler to locate WHAT causes the leak? Also note, I do not see enough disposes (ur better, using statements) in your code... You never seem to dispose the old jpg.

Comment: @TheGeneral: Well, in the code I wrote: `return bmp;     // memory leak?`. But how the bitmap could be disposed after returning it from the `Rotate()` into `e.Graphics.DrawImage(Rotate(jpg, angle), ulCorner);`? I don't know how that could be done. I thought the garbage collector would clean it.

Comment: @TomTom: That's why I asked the question. I am not aware of how that could be done. I am embedded hardware designer most of the time using C, C++ and assembler.

Comment: The problem with stuff that is having unmanaged memory is that while it uses memory, the GC does not see it. For them, those instances (image, bitmap) are TINY - very small. Mostly a pointer to unmanaged memory. Hence IDisposable - the GC will kick in, AT SOME POINT. WHich may be when the managed memory reaches 1gb, which may be when the total program memory reaches dozens of GB.

Comment: @TomTom: There has to be a way to make a small footprint program to rotate the image. When the timer is disabled the program is using only 17 MB of RAM. What if hunreds of instances of program should run in parallel?

Comment: Dispose the BitMap instance returned by `Rotate` after using it

Comment: @stuartd: That was the solution, instead of `e.Graphics.DrawImage(Rotate(jpg, angle), ulCorner);` I wrote `Bitmap bmp = Rotate(jpg, angle); e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, ulCorner); bmp.Dispose();` and now it is OK. You may write the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @Chupo_cro but it seems a bit thin for an answer. If you want to add it though with more context then do that by all means

Comment: `using var bmp = Rotate(jpg, angle);` always use a using statement when possible. It produces a pesudo finally in IL and such will dispose even when there is an exception. its less lines of code then try finally, easily to maintain, and easier to read the intention

Comment: @stuartd: Well, you knew what has to be done. I could write the solution as an answer but I don't understand why the garbage collector didn't free the unreferenced object. I was expecting it would be cleared after it was used and the `DrawImagePointF()` is exited. I think you could explain it far better than I could. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should be disposing anything that has a dispose. This usually indicates it handles and has handles to unmanaged resources, additionally makes you implicitly in control of its life cycle, and need not rely on the indeterminate nature of the garbage collector, which will in turn run when it feels like it in a way that it feels like.

Comment: Like everyone else, I looked at your code and said "whoa! there's not enough `Dispose` calls there". Go through each type to see if it's disposable, and, if it is, Dispose its instances. If you want to measure memory usage, use the ".NET Memory Counters" inside of _Performance Monitor_ (aka _PerfMon_). Nothing else will give you a good view of your memory usage

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a memory leak?

If you create lots of Images / Bitmaps without disposing them they will clutter your memory. But eventually the garbage collector will collect them.

Your application memory will rise a lot to 2? GB and then get squished back to 200? MB after every GC.

Comment: If you create a lot of bitmaps and not dispose them, you will like get a GDI out of memory error soon enough though

Comment: Yes, you were right. The GC really clears the memory after about 5 minutes when the RAM usage is about 2.5 GB and then it drops back to 20 - 30 MB and everything starts again. I didn't try if GC would free the RAM earlier when running e.g. 10 instances of the program with 16 GB of RAM. However, by disposing the bmp the program is using only 17 MB meaning hundreds of instances could run in the same time.